# Python, choose logging files' directory

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am using the Python logging library and want to choose the folder where the log files will be written.

For the moment, I made an instance of `TimedRotatingFileHandler` with the entry parameter `filename="myLogFile.log"`. This way `myLogFile.log` is created on the same folder than my python script. I want to create it into another folder.

How could I create `myLogFile.log` into , let's say, the Desktop folder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple give a different filename like `filename=r"C:\User\Matias\Desktop\myLogFile.log`

Comment: Thank you for you answer.
While typing TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename="C:User\Matias\Desktop\myLogFile.log) I get an error : " No such file or directory: D:\\User\\Labo\\Documents\\myPythonScriptFolder\\User\\Matias\\Desktop"

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Comment: Any chances you can do something like provide an environment variable as a base path?

Comment: @gaber84 Yes, you can use arbitrary python code to construct the string e.g. `filename=os.environ["MY_BASEPATH"] + "myLogFile.log"`.

Comment: ok so I have to handle it with my own code, I was naively thinking there was a default env var that the library itself was going to look up, thanks for your reply

Comment: The 'acepted' answer is fine @syntonym, if you want to statically add a file path each time you run your script. This will answer your question. 

filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
logging.basicConfig(filename=os.path.join(filename, 'log_0_0.log'), filemode='w')

Answer (score 11):

Let's say `logs` directory is in the parent directory of the current directory then you can use below 2 lines, to provide that location irrespective of the underlying `os`.

```
import os
log_dir = os.path.join(os.path.normpath(os.getcwd() + os.sep + os.pardir), 'logs')
log_fname = os.path.join(log_dir, 'log_file_name.log')
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify an absolute path when creating instance TimedRotatingFileHandler:

```
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
h = TimedRotatingFileHandler('/home/user/Desktop/myLogFile.log')
```

or

```
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
h = TimedRotatingFileHandler('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\myLogFile.log')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
This solution do not seem to work: while typing h=TimedRotatingFileHanler('D:User\Labo\Desktop') I got the error :
" No such file or directory: D:\\User\\Labo\\Documents\\myPythonScriptFolder\\User\\Labo\\Desktop"

For the constructor, filename is a relative path. I would like to give him an absolute path

Comment: in 'D:\\User\\Labo\\Documents\\myPythonScriptFolder\\User\\Labo\\Desktop' | Desktop - its directory or file name?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I soleved it in linux.

```
# log_cfg.yaml
handlers:
    file_handlers:
        ...
        filename = log//error.log
```

Comment: Equals? You sure about that?